# Tic Tac Toe game 10*10 board - Find Winner

Tags: java

I have to work on a project in my project I have to find TicTacToe game *winner*.

```
String [][]board=new String [10][10];
```

Where are 10 rows and 10 columns

I can find winner horizontally:

```
for (int I=0;I<10;I++){
    String line1=new String();
    for (int i=0;i<10;i++) {
        line1+=index[I][i];
    }
    if (line1.equals("XXXXXXXXXX")) {
        System.out.println("winner is X");///return here X
    } else if (line1.equals("OOOOOOOOOO")) {
        System.out.println("winner is O");//return here O
        }
    }
}
```

But I am not able to find a winner vertically, I have 1 option I can
hard code it but I want to code it logically like my code for
horizontally.

Comment: Swap your loops around to search vertically: outer loop `i`, inner loop `I`.

Comment: can you please code it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I have solved this problem, first rotate the array then again check using horizontally code**

```
   //first find the transpose of the index.
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
            for (int j = i; j < 10; j++){
                String temp = index[i][j];
                index[i][j] = index[j][i];
                index[j][i] = temp;
            }
        }


        //reverse each row
        for (int i = 0; i< 10; i++){
            for(int j = 0; j< 10/2; j++){
                String temp = index[i][j];
                index[i][j] = index[i][10 - 1 - j];
                index[i][10 - 1 - j] = temp;
            }
        }
```

> Now array is rotated and now i can use my Horizontally checking code.

```
for (int I=0;I<10;I++){
    String line1=new String();
    for (int i=0;i<10;i++) {
        line1+=index[I][i];
    }
    if (line1.equals("XXXXXXXXXX")) {
        System.out.println("winner is X");///return here X
    }else if (line1.equals("OOOOOOOOOO")){
        System.out.println("winner is O");//return here O
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

*It's simply first rotate the array then again check using horizontally code*

```
//first find the transpose of the index.
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
            for (int j = i; j < 10; j++){
                String temp = index[i][j];
                index[i][j] = index[j][i];
                index[j][i] = temp;
            }
        }


        //reverse each row
        for (int i = 0; i< 10; i++){
            for(int j = 0; j< 10/2; j++){
                String temp = index[i][j];
                index[i][j] = index[i][10 - 1 - j];
                index[i][10 - 1 - j] = temp;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Yeah I don't it.

Answer (score 0):

rotate the array then again check using horizontally code, it's easy

```
//first find the transpose of the index.
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
            for (int j = i; j < 10; j++){
                String temp = index[i][j];
                index[i][j] = index[j][i];
                index[j][i] = temp;
            }
        }


        //reverse each row
        for (int i = 0; i< 10; i++){
            for(int j = 0; j< 10/2; j++){
                String temp = index[i][j];
                index[i][j] = index[i][10 - 1 - j];
                index[i][10 - 1 - j] = temp;
            }
        }
```